# How do I solve this problem using Permutation and Combination?

Tags: permutations, combinations

The sum of proper divisors of 72 (1 and 72 excluded) is 
i. 195
ii.122
iii.194
iv. None of these

I have already solved it by adding the divisors (which was easy to do and the only approach I could think of), also the question was mentioned in a book whose only concern is Permutation and Combination so I am wondering if there is some another approach to this problem.

Comment: This does not require permut/combinations. You only need to list the proper divisors of $72=2^3\cdot3^2$ and add them up.

Comment: The approach that does not depend on hand counting is given by the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).  It depends on the prime factorization of the number

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, I'm voting to close this question  because it's simple enough for you to have worked out the answer by listing all the divisors. When you ask a question here it's good practice to include what you've done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: +TheSimpliFire I need an approach that solves this using permutation and combination

Comment: +Ethan The question is too easy to solve by listing all divisors but I want to know how this can be related with permutation and combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$72=2^3\cdot 3^2$, so find the number of ways you can pick from three $2$'s and two $3$'s ... though at least one of them, but not all.

That is, we pick any from zero to three $2$'s (4 options), and anywhere from zero to two $3$'s (3 options), so that's twelve different numbers, but again we can't pick none of them or all of them, so there should be ten such proper divisors.

... but that's all we can do with this problem in terms of combinations ... if you want to know the sum of all those proper divisors, you'll actually have to find them and add them.